# How can I configure log4j programmatically to show only logs from specific packages

Tags: java, log4j

When configuring log4j with xml I add categories:

```
<category name="com.myapp"> 
  <priority value="debug"/> 
  <appender-ref ref="appender1"/>
  <appender-ref ref="appender2"/>
</category>
```

I need to configure this programmatically as it's  dynamic config.
I am using this:

```
    FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();
    fa.setFile("mylog.log");
    fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
    fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
    fa.setAppend(true);
    fa.activateOptions();
    Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fa);
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    logger.debug("Hello from logger");
```

When I use the above code (as expected) I get all logs from every application using a logger - 3rd parties, logs from jars I have interest in etc. I want to allow developers to add package values into db(not required to update this at runtime) and only those to be written to the log file.